# Move central div to bottom on mobile

Tags: html, css

On desktop side columns will take a max-width of 175px leaving the center dynamic but on mobile I want to have a 2x1 grid. Also top columns will be 50% width but the height will depend on their content.

How could I move this center element to the bottom taking 100% of the width and leave the side columns next to each other taking each 50% of the width? I don't want to have hidden and duplicated elements.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.column.left,
.column.right {
  max-width: 175px;
}

.column.center {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.column.left,
.column.right {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="column left">this is a long long long long label</div>
    <div class="column center">center</div>
    <div class="column right">short label</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-wrap` and the `order` property:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.column.left,
.column.right {
  max-width: 175px;
}

.column.center {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.column.left,
.column.right {
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .column.left, .column.right {
    max-width: none;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .column.left {
    order: 1;
  }
  .column.right {
    order: 2;
  }
  .column.center {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="column left">this is a long long long long label</div>
    <div class="column center">center</div>
    <div class="column right">short label</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily enough with CSS grid and a media query. See the snippet below

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: var(--gridColTemplate, 1fr 1fr);
}

.column { text-align: center }

.column.left, .column.right { max-width: var(--sideMaxWidth, none) }
.column.center {
  grid-column: var(--centerCol, 1/-1);
  grid-row: var(--centerRow, 2);

  background-color: red;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  :root {
    --gridColTemplate: auto 1fr auto;
    --centerCol: 2/3;
    --centerRow: 1;
    --sideMaxWidth: 175px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="column left">this is a long long long long label</div>
  <div class="column center">center</div>
  <div class="column right">short label</div>
</div>
```

Comment: way to complicated as approach because the Op already uses flexbox and just adding an order property would have been easier. Also you could add the order property to a grid instead of hardcoding.